# How to solve this error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: angular, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I have created new angular project with electron.I do need to set up the electron.

I have got below errors.

**ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js**

**Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\PATH\desktop\node_modules\electron'**

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "desktop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
          "ng": "ng",
          "start": "ng serve",
          "build": "ng build",
          "test": "ng test",
          "lint": "ng lint",
          "e2e": "ng e2e",
          "electron": "ng build && electron .",
          "electron-aot": "ng build --prod && electron ."
        },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "electron": "^4.1.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }      
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681

Comment: for me this solution worked: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827

Answer (score 0):

The error is because angular-CLI does not support modules in Nodejs like "fs" and "path".

Add the following to the root of the "package.json" file.

```
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "requires": true,
  ...
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false,
    "os": false
  }
...
}
```

this solution may be helpful.

Comment: That solution doesn't work if you WANT to use this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but...

This error happens when you try to compile Node.js code with [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (which is used by Angular CLI), and that it is not configured for it. This usually means you `require`/`import` something from `electron`, or try to use Node.js APIs in your [renderer process](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model#the-renderer-process).

It's important to know that using Node.js in the renderer process is a  **[security risk](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content)**. Instead of trying to tweak your webpack configuration, you should consider following security recommendations and use a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file and [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to do what you need with Node.js stuff.

It should also be noted that if you get this error when trying to bundle your main and/or preload files, then it means you need to configure webpack with the correct [target](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/): `electron-main` and `electron-preload` respectively.